# Exception being thrown for arraycopy method in Storage

Tags: codenameone

I see the ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException for arraycopy method in Storage. Please let me know if anyone see similar issue for using storage.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900649/reading-the-crash-log/52902354

Comment: This issue seems same. As this log shows all codenameone internal files where the issue is being thrown other ticket has  com.xxxx.xxxxxx.b.n.a (ServerImpl.java:1750). So I'm not sure this is something internally triggering the issue or from my code. I'm not able to figure out as well.

Comment: I see a problem here with file encryption, we'll add a workaround for this specific exception but it might require a more thorough workaround

Comment: Hi Shai- is there any update on this. I still see the error being thrown and app gets crashed. Please advise.

Comment: Do you get this exception for Android builds made after last Friday? Is it the exact same exception?

Comment: Yes Shai. Build made on Saturday. I still see the exception as  stackoverflow.com/questions/52900649/reading-the-crash-log/. it is same exception but sometimes it show all the internal file names and sometimes it show at track location.

Comment: That's a different exception. Despite @steve-c marking them as identical and my initial comment the cause of these exceptions is very different. This issue is resolved.