# Reading the crash log

Tags: codenameone

I see ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception thrown but there are three different methods in the following lines in the code. How would I read the log to find out which of the following lines the error being thrown at. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exception from writing to an encrypted storage. It's thrown by the cypher code. It's unclear why this failed or due to what action but it might be related to logging.

Comment: related logging means? what can i do to avoid this crash on the device. I'm attaching the writing to storage code. Please let me know if any thing causes this issue. I'm using the preference also.

Comment: If I had to venture a guess it would be that you have background location turned on and encryption might be off when you get that specific event.

Comment: Hi Shai- is there any update on this. I still see the error being thrown and App gets crashed. Please advise. As you mentioned in this ticket you will add work around for this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900596/exception-being-thrown-for-arraycopy-method-in-storage

Comment: These are different exceptions with different reasons. This happens because `TrackLocation` runs the timer with encryption misconfigured

Comment: shai...I have verified the code and i dot see anything wrong in my code. There should be something triggering internally. This happens once in a while and there could be some glitch or something in the library. Please advise.

Comment: `TrackLocation` line 52 might execute when encryption isn't properly set-up. That's the case when this can happen.

Comment: Shai...how does this happen? Please advise. I will set up encryption in main init() method which gets called before any other call happens including track location. Please see the code below: public void init(Object context) {
Preferences.setPreferencesLocation("EncryptedPreferences");
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile(Cookie.STORAGE_NAME);
}

Comment: Do you think there is any other method that gets called before init() method of Main class. Please advise

Comment: That's not the encrypt call, that just renames the files

Comment: I'm calling install on EncryptedStorage in  Main class:   EncryptedStorage.install("XXABCDR65k812abcdefghgKaaa12356") and not calling or using the storage class any where else. When will the Storage gets setup. Please advise.

Comment: In which part of the main class? Where do you setup the timer? If it starts from static context it might start sooner

Comment: setting up storage in the beginning lines of init method in  main class. Timer set in separate class Track Location when gets called only during the login of the application.When I debug the code Main class gets called before displaying the  Login screen where as track location will be called during login of the aoplication. Please let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: Is there global static code that can trigger the timer? A static intializer or statically invoked global code?

Comment: I'm using the code for tracklocation in the comments. This code only called after the login of  the application. Please advise.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one timer running at once? More than one path in the code using that file?

Comment: No Shai. This is the only called once in the project. Please advise as I see this issue. Also, is there any workaround to temporarily fix this issue. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Also, this is only happening on Android devices. Please advise.

Comment: This happens when you invoke `writeObject` in your timer polling code. You can probably catch the exception. Regardless the exception is a failure to log which might be a result of a cascading error that's now hidden. You can try deleting the old log, I've added a new API which will be there Friday: `Log.deleteLog()`. You can use that to delete the log immediately after you activate encryption

Comment: Gr8. Thanks for the advise Shai.

Comment: Shai, does the encryption gets activated when EncryptedStorage.install() is called. Shall I add the deleteLog() statement after this. Please advise.

Comment: Yes after that.